404 with google ads query params
any idea how to fix 404s for existing pages caused by Google Ads query params?
See following in access log
www.hedonia.sk 85.237.224.49 - - [17/Oct/2024:06:39:27 +0200] "GET /aktualne-obaly-pre-donasku-rozvoz-jedla-a-vydaj-cez-okienko/?_gl=1*3nv7ei*_up*MQ..&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyL24BhCtARIsALo0fSATukxCHZvkzV1H0q18rAtJSzes6h8cJRkJOa9768PZT4rweP_8rS8aAjDcEALw_wcB&gbraid=0AAAAAD4J6GCVIhkqqVr3_47Q7yQUEBHsj HTTP/3.0" 404 14398 "https://www.hedonia.sk/?_gl=1*3nv7ei*_up*MQ..&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyL24BhCtARIsALo0fSATukxCHZvkzV1H0q18rAtJSzes6h8cJRkJOa9768PZT4rweP_8rS8aAjDcEALw_wcB&gbraid=0AAAAAD4J6GCVIhkqqVr3_47Q7yQUEBHsj" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" 0.606 MISS 10.31.40.12:80 0.603 () 
www.hedonia.sk 85.237.224.49 - - [17/Oct/2024:06:53:45 +0200] "GET /aktualne-obaly-pre-donasku-rozvoz-jedla-a-vydaj-cez-okienko/?_gl=1*1qeq00y*_up*MQ..&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyL24BhCtARIsALo0fSATukxCHZvkzV1H0q18rAtJSzes6h8cJRkJOa9768PZT4rweP_8rS8aAjDcEALw_wcB&gbraid=0AAAAAD4J6GCVIhkqqVr3_47Q7yQUEBHsj HTTP/3.0" 404 14396 "https://www.hedonia.sk/?_gl=1*3nv7ei*_up*MQ..&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyL24BhCtARIsALo0fSATukxCHZvkzV1H0q18rAtJSzes6h8cJRkJOa9768PZT4rweP_8rS8aAjDcEALw_wcB&gbraid=0AAAAAD4J6GCVIhkqqVr3_47Q7yQUEBHsj" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" 0.823 MISS 10.31.40.12:80 0.820 () 

Looks like only issue on iPhone/Safari, preserves query params after click
